# Getting the favorite_count of a retweet Twitter REST API - twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, twitter-gem

I'm unable to get the favorite_count of a retweet from the JSON response of the Twitter REST api using the twitter-gem for my ROR app. The response returns 0 for the favorite_count of retweets. Is there a way to obtain this value from the response or it just doesn't support it?

Comment: please at least add a basic, cleaned-up version of the code you tried

Comment: also, there is no like count, but there is a favorite_count, is that what you meant?

Comment: yes it's the favorite_count. Any of the endpoints like GET home_timeline if it is a retweet the favorite_count returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint for it : https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/:id.json

id : The numerical ID of the desired status.

Parameter : favorite_count.

A sample response:

```
    [
      {contributors":null,
       "coordinates":null,
       "created_at":"Tue Sep 09 23:44:05 +0000 2014",
       "entities":{  },
       "favorite_count":169,
       "favorited":false,
        ...
      }
    ]
```

For further info, visit [official doc](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid).